# How to push new results from pagination inside component that uses BehavioralSubjects

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In my angular app I'm using this logic to get paginated results from API:

Inside my service I'm creating functions to update the apiResponseBehavior that is responsible to store data from the API

```js
private categorySubject = new BehaviorSubject<number | null>(null);
  apiBehavior$ = new BehaviorSubject<ApiResponseInterface>({
    data: [],
    next_cursor: '',
    prev_page_url: '',
  });
cursor = ''

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService) {}

  apiResponseOf(): Observable<ApiResponseInterface> {
    return this.apiBehavior$;
  }
  getQuestions(page = this.cursor, category = this.categorySubject.getValue()): void {
    let url = category ? `${this.baseUrl}/category/${category}` : this.baseUrl;
    const params = new HttpParams().set('cursor', page);
    this.http.get<ApiResponseInterface>(url, { params }).subscribe((res) => {
      this.apiBehavior$.next(res);
    });

setCursor(page: string) {
    this.cursor = page;
  }
```

Inside my component, I am subscribing to the apiBehavior as observable returned by the `apiResponseOf()` to get the data from the API and store it inside the `questions` array, I'm also storing the new cursor page inside the `cursorPage`

```js
apiResponse$?: Observable<ApiResponseInterface>;
  questions?: QuestionsInterface[];
  cursorPage = '';
  constructor(private questionsService: QuestionsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apiResponse$ = this.questionsService.apiResponseOf();
    this.apiResponse$.subscribe((res) => {
      this.questions = res.data;
      this.cursorPage = res.next_cursor;
    });
  }
```

what I need to do now is implement a "load more" functionality: clicking on a specific button the new results page should be requested from the API and then pushed to the `questions` array, I'm trying to do that using this function:

```js
loadMore() {
    if (this.apiResponse$ === undefined || !this.cursorPage) {
      console.log('No more questions');
      return;
    }
    this.questionsService.setCursor(this.cursorPage);
    this.apiResponse$.subscribe((res) => {
      this.questions?.push(...res.data);
      this.cursorPage = res.next_cursor;
    });
  }
```

The problem here is that data is behaving strangely and is pushing the same content already present making the data duplicate, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try :
loadMore() {
    if (this.apiResponse$ === undefined || !this.cursorPage) {
      console.log('No more questions');
      return;
    }
    this.questionsService.setCursor(this.cursorPage);
    this.questionsService.getQuestions();
  }

It will trigger the fetch of new questions, and pass them to the apiBehavior$.
And your questions will be automatically updated.

Comment: thanks for the answer, your solution seems to overwrite the data, what I need is to push new data inside the array without loosing the previous

Comment: Ok inside your ngOnInit : this.apiResponse$.subscribe((res) => {
      this.questions.push(...res.data);
      this.cursorPage = res.next_cursor;
    });